# Accessing protected members from outside with this trick, but is this valid?

Tags: c++

If I have the following class:

```
class Foo
{
protected:
    int i;
public:
    Foo() : i(42) {}
};
```

Naturally, I don't have access to protected members from the outside, but I can do this little trick: first I create a new class which inherits Foo:

```
class Foo2 : public Foo
{
public:
    int GetI() { return i; }
};
```

Now, whenever I have an instance of Foo or a pointer to such instance, I can access protected member via casting (since I don't use any additional members):

```
Foo *f = new Foo();
Foo f2;
std::cout << ((Foo2*)f)->GetI() << std::endl;
std::cout << (reinterpret_cast<Foo2&>(f2)).GetI() << std::endl;
```

I understand why this works, but will there ever be any bad consequences? Compiler doesn't mind, there aren't any run time checks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
reinterpret_cast<Foo2&>(f2)).GetI()
```

Technically, this is Undefined behavior. So it might work but it does not have to.

Comment: Didn't know that, but can the pointer trick still be used though?

Comment: It
 doesn't answer the main question, how about `((Foo2*)f)->GetI()`?

Comment: @ToniPetrina: Since it does not guarantee you the desired result. No you should not use it. You should only write code which gives you guaranteed results.

Comment: @MM.: It answers the Q unless you don't understand what Undefined behavior means. That is still undefined behavior.

Comment: @ToniPetrina you can do a similar (and well-defined) trick by allowing `Foo2` to be constructed from a `Foo` instance.  Then you can get the same results from `Foo2(f).GetI();`

Comment: @ToniPetrina: For me the more important Q is why do u need this trick? access specification is not for fooling the compiler it is a means to achieve maintainable and well designed code which humans have to maintain not the compiler.

Comment: @AlokSave My colleague needed it for a workaround for some MFC bug. I just found it really interesting that it works.

Comment: @DrewDormann But this creates a copy of an original object so to speak. In case I wish to modify the original object, this is not a good solution.

Comment: @ToniPetrina That's correct.  Although it is a good solution for the question you posted.

Comment: @DrewDormann But if I store reference to the base class instance in a derived class instance, I might be able to modify the original captured object.

Comment: @ToniPetrina Also correct.  :)  Be careful with object lifetimes though.

Comment: Though in the general case correct, I think this simplistic example hits on a special exception. It is a standard layout type (as it lacks virtuals and the derived class adds no new data, all data same access, etc). So yeah, in general you are right, but this simplistic example may be an exception due to the rules of standard layout types.

Answer (score 1):

You're down casting a `Foo` object to a `Foo2` object.

> A downcast is a cast from a base class to a class derived from the
>   base class. A downcast is only safe if the object addressed at runtime
>   is actually addressing a derived class object

To protect your code, you must use `dynamic_cast` to check a downcast is valid or not.

Using `reinterpret_cast` is not recommended for down-casting. Use `static_cast` or `dynamic_cast`.

Reading chunk of articles, many wrote *DO NOT USE DOWN CASTING* like you did. One dangerous example is to have a `virtual void GetI()` in `Foo`.

Comment: *"Using `reinterpret_cast` is not recommanded because of compiler depended behaviors."* is misleading to the point of being wrong. The standard provides certain guarantees with `reinterpret_cast` usage pretty much like any other construct in the language. If you go beyond those boundaries Undefined behavior is what you get. That is not the reason one should/should not recommend `reinterpret_cast`.

Comment: I get that dynamic cast will prevent me from doing so. Do you know what possible problems one might encounter by using the trick above?